# Can google calendar api call return a promise inside angular factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, google-calendar-api

Can i change this code so it returns a promise?

```
var calApi = {
fun3: function() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, calApi.fun2);
},
fun2: function(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        calApi.fun4();
    }
},
fun1: function(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
        calApi.fun2);
    return false;
},
fun4: function() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', calApi.fun5);
}, 
fun5: function() {
    // some code
    // returning the result...
}
};
return calApi;
```

my controller:

```
$scope.hanleAPICall = function(event) {
    factoryName.fun1(event);
};
```

this code is taken from google [calendar api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name) and im trying to implement it in a angularjs factory, but i need to return the result of the events from the api as a promise as im returning the events, but nothing happen inside my page.

Comment: `gapi.client.load(...)` and other returns promise?

Comment: i think none of them are returning promises as you can see in the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample)

Comment: If the return value is not a promise you can always make it into a promise using angular $q module.

Comment: @UriBrecher, yes, thats true, but in this case the fun1 is calling fun2 which is calling other functions and i dont know how exactly to do it in order it to work... ;(

Comment: @MaximShoustin, it is not returning a promise

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. After a few layers of authorisation eventually fun5 is called and suppose to do something. Do you want fun5 to generate a promise? Is fun5 implemented by you? I think your question is lacking some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below to return a promise in service:

```
angular.module('app', [])
 .factory('AppService', function ($q) {
   return {
     fun3: fun3
   };

  function fun3() {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    gapi.auth.authorize(
      {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
        'immediate': true
      }, handleAuthResult);

    function handleAuthResult (authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        defer.resolve(authResult);
      } else {
        defer.reject(authResult.error);
      }
    }

    return defer.promise;
  }
});
```

Similar to above you can create factory methods for your other methods `fun1, fun2, fun4, fun5`

Answer (score 1):

You can Promisify everything, 
what's you need (in my opinion) is a Wrapper around the `gapi` library, that's all.

Right now:

1. Avoid global variables, create two constants (GAPI_CLIENT_ID, GAPI_SCOPES)
2. Create a `[Service][1]` that does what `gapi` does but in an angular way.

That's should be a little refactoring of your code...

```js
function GapiServiceFactory($q, GAPI_CLIENT_ID, GAPI_SCOPES) {
  var self = this;
  
  /**
   * @private
  **/
  self._authorize = function(immediate) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var data = {
      client_id: GAPI_CLIENT_ID, 
      scope: GAPI_SCOPES, 
      immediate: !!immediate
    };
    
    gapi.auth.authorize(data, function(result) {   
      if(Object.hasOwnProperty.call(result, 'error')) {
        return deferred.reject(result);
      }
      
      return deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    
    return deferred.promise;
  };
  
  self.authorize = function() {
    return self._authorize(false);
  };
  
  self.authorizeImmediate = function() {
    return self._authorize(true);
  };
  
  self.loadCalendar = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
      
      if(/**What's the logic here? **/) {
        return deferred.reject();
      }
      
      return deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
}

angular
  .module('Test', [])
  .constant('GAPI_CLIENT_ID', 12333)
  .constant('GAPI_SCOPES', ['read', 'write'])
  .service('GapiService', GapiServiceFactory)
  .controller('TestCtrl', function TestCtrl(GapiService) {
    GapiService
      .authorizeImmediate()
      .then(
        console.log.bind(console, 'Authorization success'), 
        console.log.bind(console, 'Authorization error')
      )
    ;
  
    GapiService
      .loadCalendar()
      .then(
        console.log.bind(console, 'LoadCalendar success'), 
        console.log.bind(console, 'LoadCalendar error')
      )
    ;    
  })
;
```